# Are there any Opensource, free XF.Network analogs (product for creating fast servers with .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Opensource, free [XF.Network](http://www.kodart.com/)  analogs (product for [creating High Performance TCP/IP Server using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/high-performance-server.aspx))

Comment: What language are you looking to program in? What network environment? Are you mentioning .NET because XF.Network is in .NET, or are you mentioning .NET because you're trying to program in .NET?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [spserver](http://code.google.com/p/spserver/).